# Is CSV file partitioned and parallelized multiply?

Tags: apache-spark

I'm new to Apache Spark.

I have issue about spark. If someone know to solve it, please advise me.

[Environment]

Cluster with Standalone Mode : master node and 3 worker nodes which have four cores respectively

[Scenario]

1. CSV file is loaded and dataset is created. At this time, partition number of dataset is one.
2. Dataset is repartitioned to 10.
3. 10 partitions should be parallelized at 3 worker nodes.

[Issue]

At the above No.3, I could confirm that 10 partitions were created from execution log.
However, all 10 partitions were processed at ONLY ONE worker node.

With regard to my cluster, I have already tried following example of SparkPi with 10 partitions and they were parallelized at 3 worker nodes.
https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/SparkPi.scala

Thus, I recognized the cluster itself was working correctly.

[Driver program]

I don't write anything special other than repartition method for distributed processing.

[Question]

Is CSV file partitioned and parallelized multiply?

Comment: Quick point: executors are what matter in spark, not nodes. That is to say you could have all the data processed on one node but because you have several executors available on that node it could have still been distributed evenly and processed fine. That said, shuffle is expensive in spark. My guess is the spark catalyst engine may be making a decision to process all of the data on one node to avoid the cost of shuffling the data around to the other nodes. You can test this out by either forcing the data to be available on the other nodes, ie replicate across nodes, or using a larger dataset.

Comment: Hi r0bb23, I could confirm that CSV file partitioned and parallelized multiply by using a larger dataset. Thank you for your cooperation!